# Basement refrigerator copper line leak

Tags: water, leak, pipe, refrigerator, copper

I have an issue with a flexible copper pipe in the basement ceiling occasionally dripping cold water

[image: copper pipe with drip locations circled]

There is no spraying - just slow drips.

I noticed condensation issues in the basement on hot humid days. When the AC is running I don't see the fridge copper line drip water - is this a leak in the pipe or a condensation issue? LG Refrigerator is on the floor directly above the basement spot.

Thanks to suggestions to do some additional digging, this leak was discovered behind the fridge.

[image: valve on the back of the fridge, noting location of wetness]

Comment: Condensation should make a lot of the pipe damp.  Check the pipe when there is a drop and see if there is a wet damp line coming from the top, if there is then you have a very slow leak.  Dry air from AC might be enough to dry it up before it drips, but humid air will allow it to drip.  The wood where the pipe comes from, looks wet.

Comment: The Look at the wood where the line comes through the floor, it looks wet to me. As this is a single pipe it’s doubtful that it is an AC issue I would be looking above the floor for a leak at a connection point.

Comment: I found the source of leak at the back of the refrigerator - any idea what is causing the leak? https://i.imgur.com/KokaY7G.jpg

Comment: Follow the water, when it stops that probably where the leak is.  Water always flows downward.  Copper connection is a bit loose or not sealed right, or water is coming from blue part or beyond.

Comment: The water can come from condensation on the line on the first floor. Insulate the exposed line on the first floor and seal the floor penetration, then you can determine where is the water from (usually the condensation is formed on the line in a not well-ventilated place, such as the ceiling of the basement where heat gathering the most and difficult to vent).

Comment: It is mostly likely the blue inlet valve has developed a leak - I see it leaking. This seems like a common LG problem. Found the part from reddit https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B081S421DT/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_glt_fabc_3TSMW6513VTE3Z67FP80 and plenty of YouTube videos to replace. Just ordered the replacement. I agree with you on the insulation.

Comment: You seem to have found the answer to your question. Please write it up as an answer, then, when the system lets you, click the check mark. This will help others to know that this has a working answer.

Comment: How is the leak in the second picture is causing the dripping down the copper into the basement?  That would cause puddling behind the fridge.  The copper appears to go up and away.  The comment that it stops when the AC is on is a clear sign it's a condensation issue.

Comment: @rtaft We can guess that the puddle on the floor finds its way to the place where the copper pipe penetrates the floor and there couples from floor to pipe. Condensation happens when a surface temperature is below the surrounding air's dew point. This pipe is unlikely to be cold enough for condensate to form -- unless there is continuous flow of rather cold water through the pipe, it would soon be warmed to room temperature and so be too warm for condensation to occur. It's possible that running AC dries the air enough to evaporate the puddle and avoid water wicking down the copper tube.

Comment: happy to report the water inlet valve replacement fixed the refrigerator leak, the existing valve (blue plastic) developed a crack. This was not a case of condensation, just a stream of leaking water running down the copper pipe into the basement.

Answer (score 1):

It is mostly likely **the blue inlet valve has developed a leak** - I see it leaking. This seems like a common LG problem. Found the part from reddit https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B081S421DT/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_glt_fabc_3TSMW6513VTE3Z67FP80 and plenty of YouTube videos to replace. Just ordered the replacement. I agree with you on the insulation.